# python: Selecting from mysql table

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to select the region of a country from a mysql table using Python. However, when I write the following code:

```
cur.execute("select region from player_list where country = %" % (country))
```

I get the following error message:

> ValueError: incomplete format

I am not 100% certain what the proper format is for getting this information from a mysql table using mysql.connector.

Comment: Is `country` a string? Did you miss quotes around `%` ?

Comment: `cur.execute("select region from player_list where country = '%s'" % (country))`

Comment: Yes thank you. This was correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

`cur.execute("select region from player_list where country = {0}".format(country))`

Answer (score 0):

It's could depend on your ORM, but for me, the right syntax are :

```
cur.execute("select region from player_list where country = %s", [country])
```